# Unable to send data to another activity from adapter class

Tags: kotlin, android-intent

I list of users showing on home fragment when user clicks any item it should show another activity where data should pass from previous activity.I am using `putExtra` method to pass data but it is not sending any data.

Below is my  code:

**UserAdapter.kt**

```
class UserAdapter(private val context: Context, private val userList:List<User>): RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserAdapter.ViewHolder {
  return ViewHolder(UserRowBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent,false))
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    val model = userList[position]
    holder.binding.name.text = model.name
    holder.binding.city.text = model.city
    holder.binding.email.text = model.email

    holder.binding.layout.setOnClickListener {
     //   Toast.makeText(context,model.name,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        val intent = Intent(context, DetailActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, model.name)
        context.startActivity(intent)
    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return userList.size
}

class ViewHolder(val binding:UserRowBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)

}
```

**DetailActivity.kt**

```
class DetailActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding:ActivityDetailBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityDetailBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    val message = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_MESSAGE")
    Toast.makeText(this,message,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

    binding.msg.text = message

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the value of `EXTRA_MESSAGE ` in your Adapter?

Comment: Yeah `model.name` is showing the value in adapter class

Comment: My question was that if the value assigned to variable `EXTRA_MESSAGE` is the same as in `DetailActivity` -> `"EXTRA_MESSAGE"`

Comment: yeah its the same

Comment: If you are sure about that why don't you try adding a breakpoint and check what intent.extras gives you

Comment: Please post the code you use to define `EXTRA_MESSAGE` in the adapter.

Comment: What is the defined type of `model.name`?